# WSO2 IS authenticate PKI user

Tags: wso2, pki, wso2-identity-server

Does WSO2 IS support user with PKI authentications?
I found one Blog at http://venurakahawala.blogspot.com/2013/12/custom-authenticator-for-pki-with-wso2.html is quite encouraging, but maven build fails. 
Documentation of WSO2 IS 5.0.0. "Creating Custom Authenticators" did not mention any PKI custom authenticator creations. Any suggestions/comments/ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

could you provide more information why did it fail? Checking the POM (I did not try to compile) I see there are many dependencies hardcoded which may not be valid anymore. These tutorials are often principial, not all of them work out of box (after repository or dependencies change). Simply try another.

There are several blogs and posts about mutual SSL authentication. All of them assume knowledge of the Identity Server, PKI and configuring the project details (so they don't bother with setting the user store, user's certificate in the store, correct dependencies, etc).

I personally like the following blog (https://darray.wordpress.com/2013/12/17/mutuall-ssl-with-wso2-identity-server/ ) with examples and source code, it worked, dependencies are much simpler. Please note the examples are usually bound to a specific version of the Identity Server

Comment: Maven build fails because source code in svn are missing entire two packages of source code. (it is incomplete source tree). Not because of dependencies hardcoded here.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 IS supports PKI authenticators. You can check [inwebo authenticator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/Inwebo+Authenticator+and+Provisioning+Connector) and [X509Certificate authenticator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/X509Certificate+Authenticator).